# Python - how to extract list or dictionary from String?

Tags: python, string, list, dictionary, type-conversion

how to extract list or dictionary from String ?
**Convert String to List and Dictionary**

I want to iterat through the list to print the dictionary value but i am not able to convert that string into list with proper format.

```
pro = '[{"name": "Ingenious Film Partners", "id": 289}, {"name": "Twentieth Century Fox Film Corporation", "id": 306}]'
print(type(pro))
<class 'str'>
```

i want list from the string but when i try to convert string into list it will return each character as list element.

```
pro = list(pro)
print(pro)
['[', '{', '"', 'n', 'a',........'6', '}', ']']
```

but i want to list with dictionary elements.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert string representation of list to list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1894269/convert-string-representation-of-list-to-list)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert string representation of list to list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1894269/convert-string-representation-of-list-to-list)

Answer (score 0):

That's a string in JSON format, you could use:

```
import json

pro = '[{"name": "Ingenious Film Partners", "id": 289}, {"name": "Twentieth Century Fox Film Corporation", "id": 306}]'
o = json.loads()

print(o[0]['name'])
```

Answer (score 0):

run this:

```
import json
pro = '[{"name": "Ingenious Film Partners", "id": 289}, {"name": "Twentieth Century Fox Film Corporation", "id": 306}]'
print(type(pro))
jsonData=json.loads(pro)
print(type(jsonData))
print(jsonData[0]["name"])
```